# Github и разные свойства проекта в visual studio

Tags: git, зависимости

Хотелось бы ввести проект на двух разных устройствах, но при этом библиотеки, которые я использую, находятся в разных местах. Как лучше организовать?
Есть пару вариантов как можно сделать
1)Настроить проект и закинуть файл проекта в git ignore 
2)Положить все зависимости в папку проекта и как-то прописать относительный путь(пробовал через $, не получилось, не нашел как это сделать)
Какой вариант можете предложить? Спасибо

Comment: при помощи Git на 2-х компах низя кодить))) GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket нужен

Comment: Неправильно выразился, имелось ввиду использование github

Comment: @Данил можно. Разворачиваете git-сервер в локальной сети, работаете с ним с любого количества компов, без внешних сервисов.

Comment: @insolor окей, допустим, но зачем так жизнь парить? Я сам true-программист но таким я еще себя не мучил

Comment: @Данил, затем что может быть закрытая сеть (без выхода в интернет), какой-то закрытый проект, который не нужно светить наружу.

Comment: ну так github private можно сделать....

Comment: @Данил, но он не будет работать без интернета. Плюс могут быть какие-то жесткие требования, что исходники ни в коем случае не должны покидать пределов локальной сети.

Comment: ну ладно, твоя взяла